# MarkLogic 8 - information in log file

Tags: marklogic

This is my 184 lines long error log after I made some mistake in my REST endpoint in MarkLogic 8. Is there anything in this collection of log lines that could help me pinpoint the actual problem?

The following line seems to be a message trying to explain what went wrong but no matter what I mess up, this message is always the same.

**Single Line**

```
Status 500: RESTAPI-INVALIDRESULT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid result:  reason: soap2 extension produced 0 results and 1 mime types: POST
```

I've also followed a couple of 'line' and 'column' combinations but they do not point to my REST extension (the .sjs file).

**Log**

```
2015-07-29 19:10:03.607 Info: [Event:id=dikw-post] username test
2015-07-29 19:10:03.608 Info: [Event:id=dikw-post] language nl
2015-07-29 19:10:03.608 Info: [Event:id=dikw-post] application testapp
2015-07-29 19:10:03.609 Info: [Event:id=dikw-post] trackingNumbers testTrack01
2015-07-29 19:10:03.610 Info: [Event:id=dikw-post] Tracking testTrack01
2015-07-29 19:10:03.611 Info: [Event:id=dikw-post] Post took PT0.014765S
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap: RESTAPI-INVALIDRESULT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid result:  reason: soap2 extension produced 0 results and 1 mime types: POST
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap: in /MarkLogic/rest-api/models/resource-model-common.xqy, at 105:13,
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap: in rsrcmodcom:collect-documents("POST", "soap2", map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="output-status"><map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">...</map:map>), ()) [1.0-ml]
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $resource-name = "POST"
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $method = "soap2"
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $context = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="output-status"><map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">...</map:map>)
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $results = ()
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $result-count = xs:unsignedLong("0")
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $output-types = "application/xml"
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $output-types = "application/xml"
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $output-count = xs:unsignedLong("1")
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $boundary = ()
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap: in /MarkLogic/rest-api/models/resource-model-query.xqy, at 252:19,
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap: in rsrcmodqry:resource-post("soap2", map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="output-status"><map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">...</map:map>), map:map(), document{text{"&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soa..."}}, fn:false(), local:rsrcmod-callback#6) [1.0-ml]
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $resource-name = "soap2"
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $context = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="output-status"><map:value xsi:type="xs:integer">...</map:map>)
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $resource-params = map:map()
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $input = document{text{"&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soa..."}}
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $in-txn = fn:false()
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $responder = local:rsrcmod-callback#6
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $service = xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/soap2","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/soap2/assets/resource.xqy")
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap: in /MarkLogic/rest-api/models/resource-model-query.xqy, at 219:4,
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap: in rsrcmodqry:exec-post(map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="accept-language"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string"...</map:map>), map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="name"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">soap2</map...</map:map>), document{text{"&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soa..."}}, local:rsrcmod-callback#6) [1.0-ml]
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $headers = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="accept-language"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string"...</map:map>)
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $endpoint-params = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="name"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">soap2</map...</map:map>)
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $input = document{text{"&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soa..."}}
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $responder = local:rsrcmod-callback#6
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap: in /MarkLogic/rest-api/endpoints/resource-service-query.xqy, at 65:8 [1.0-ml]
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $params = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="name"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string">soap2</map...</map:map>)
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $headers = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"><map:entry key="accept-language"><map:value xsi:type="xs:string"...</map:map>)
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $method = "POST"
2015-07-29 19:10:03.619 Notice: dikw-pddd-soap:   $body = document{text{"&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soa..."}}
2015-07-29 19:10:03.796 Info: dikw-pddd-soap: Status 500: RESTAPI-INVALIDRESULT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid result:  reason: soap2 extension produced 0 results and 1 mime types: POST
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap: <error:error xsi:schemaLocation="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error error.xsd" xmlns:error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:   <error:code>RESTAPI-INVALIDRESULT</error:code>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:   <error:name>err:FOER0000</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:   <error:xquery-version>1.0-ml</error:xquery-version>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:   <error:message>Invalid result: </error:message>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:   <error:format-string>RESTAPI-INVALIDRESULT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid result:  reason: soap2 extension produced 0 results and 1 mime types: POST</error:format-string>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:   <error:retryable>false</error:retryable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:   <error:expr> </error:expr>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:   <error:data>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:     <error:datum>soap2 extension produced 0 results and 1 mime types: POST</error:datum>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:   </error:data>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:   <error:stack>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:     <error:frame>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:uri>/MarkLogic/rest-api/models/resource-model-common.xqy</error:uri>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:line>105</error:line>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:column>13</error:column>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:operation>rsrcmodcom:collect-documents("POST", "soap2", map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"&gt;&lt;map:entry key="output-status"&gt;&lt;map:value xsi:type="xs:integer"&gt;...&lt;/map:map&gt;), ())</error:operation>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:variables>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-common">resource-name</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>"POST"</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-common">method</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>"soap2"</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-common">context</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"&gt;&lt;map:entry key="output-status"&gt;&lt;map:value xsi:type="xs:integer"&gt;...&lt;/map:map&gt;)</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-common">results</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>()</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-common">result-count</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>xs:unsignedLong("0")</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-common">output-types</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>"application/xml"</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-common">output-types</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>"application/xml"</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-common">output-count</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>xs:unsignedLong("1")</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-common">boundary</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>()</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       </error:variables>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:xquery-version>1.0-ml</error:xquery-version>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:     </error:frame>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:     <error:frame>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:uri>/MarkLogic/rest-api/models/resource-model-query.xqy</error:uri>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:line>252</error:line>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:column>19</error:column>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:operation>rsrcmodqry:resource-post("soap2", map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"&gt;&lt;map:entry key="output-status"&gt;&lt;map:value xsi:type="xs:integer"&gt;...&lt;/map:map&gt;), map:map(), document{text{"&amp;lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soa..."}}, fn:false(), local:rsrcmod-callback#6)</error:operation>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:variables>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-query">resource-name</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>"soap2"</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-query">context</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"&gt;&lt;map:entry key="output-status"&gt;&lt;map:value xsi:type="xs:integer"&gt;...&lt;/map:map&gt;)</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-query">resource-params</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>map:map()</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-query">input</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>document{text{"&amp;lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soa..."}}</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-query">in-txn</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>fn:false()</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-query">responder</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>local:rsrcmod-callback#6</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-query">service</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>xdmp:function(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/soap2","post"), "/marklogic.rest.resource/soap2/assets/resource.xqy")</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       </error:variables>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:xquery-version>1.0-ml</error:xquery-version>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:     </error:frame>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:     <error:frame>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:uri>/MarkLogic/rest-api/models/resource-model-query.xqy</error:uri>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:line>219</error:line>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:column>4</error:column>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:operation>rsrcmodqry:exec-post(map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"&gt;&lt;map:entry key="accept-language"&gt;&lt;map:value xsi:type="xs:string"...&lt;/map:map&gt;), map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"&gt;&lt;map:entry key="name"&gt;&lt;map:value xsi:type="xs:string"&gt;soap2&lt;/map...&lt;/map:map&gt;), document{text{"&amp;lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soa..."}}, local:rsrcmod-callback#6)</error:operation>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:variables>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-query">headers</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"&gt;&lt;map:entry key="accept-language"&gt;&lt;map:value xsi:type="xs:string"...&lt;/map:map&gt;)</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-query">endpoint-params</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"&gt;&lt;map:entry key="name"&gt;&lt;map:value xsi:type="xs:string"&gt;soap2&lt;/map...&lt;/map:map&gt;)</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-query">input</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>document{text{"&amp;lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soa..."}}</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/resource-model-query">responder</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>local:rsrcmod-callback#6</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       </error:variables>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:xquery-version>1.0-ml</error:xquery-version>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:     </error:frame>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:     <error:frame>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:uri>/MarkLogic/rest-api/endpoints/resource-service-query.xqy</error:uri>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:line>65</error:line>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:column>8</error:column>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:variables>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="">params</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"&gt;&lt;map:entry key="name"&gt;&lt;map:value xsi:type="xs:string"&gt;soap2&lt;/map...&lt;/map:map&gt;)</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="">headers</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>map:map(&lt;map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"&gt;&lt;map:entry key="accept-language"&gt;&lt;map:value xsi:type="xs:string"...&lt;/map:map&gt;)</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="">method</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>"POST"</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  <error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:name xmlns="">body</error:name>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:    <error:value>document{text{"&amp;lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soa..."}}</error:value>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:  </error:variable>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       </error:variables>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:       <error:xquery-version>1.0-ml</error:xquery-version>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:     </error:frame>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap:   </error:stack>
2015-07-29 19:10:03.797 Debug: dikw-pddd-soap: </error:error>
```

**Details**

Let's say I make a typo in my script, will the 'error' log help me find this typo in any way? Or will it just tell me 'something is wrong' by telling me the response was empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your resource extension must return the same number of documents as mime types in the output-types key of the context map:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions

The error indicates that the extension is declaring a mime type but not returning a document.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks. This is a result of a mistake in my JavaScript code. I'm looking for an indicator regarding this problem. I've added some more info to my question.

Comment: In this case, the log can only tell you something is wrong, not where it is wrong. The error is discovered when checking the output from the resource service extension.  So, no, unfortunately, there is no way for the framework to indicate which line within the code should either not be setting the output-types or should be returning a document.

Comment: Do you know of any way to find these errors, or any specific error, in the JavaScript code? At this moment, a single typo may take me a whole day to find. With a 10k lines script, this is not longer workable.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question.  The class of error identified above -- a problem in the output returned from a resource service that runs to completion -- is very different from JavaScript syntax or runtime errors in the resource service that causes execution of the service to fail.  A syntax error should report a stack trace that starts with the line having the error.  Is that not happening?

Comment: No, any error in the JavaScript code results in an empty response and therefore in the same error message.

Comment: I've confirmed that neither a syntax error at installation nor a runtime execution error in the JavaScript code report a stack trace with debug enabled.  That's a bug. You should be able to get a stack trace for those two classes of errors.

Answer (score 1):

To put it short, your REST extension is not returning output, while it is expecting at least something. This is not because of a typo (you would have seen a compile error at deploy time), but a matter of faulty logic in your code.

Take the body of your appropriate extension method function, and run it in QC to isolate the issue..

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, this copy/pasting is a cumbersome method which I was hoping to circumvent. The Query Console is good to test with but not something to develop in.